# Polymer 2.0 errors

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have worked with Polymer 1.x for a while and I want to start a project from scratch with Polymer 2.0 but I get many errors. I am building a PWA as I did before, therefor I included a service worker and a manifest.json file. The errors I get are, I think, most of incompatibility between versions since they claim some classes not defined or undefined "window" object (like in the second error)

For versions I followed this guide (point: Upgrade an existing project)

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#polymer-1-compatibility-layer

First error:

```
platinum-sw-register.html:111 
Uncaught ReferenceError: HTMLImports is not defined at platinum-sw-register.html:111
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeMethods' of undefined
    at pa (style-util.js:243)
    at p.u (style-properties.js:499)
    at k.T (scoping-shim.js:299)
    at k.styleElement (scoping-shim.js:243)
    at Object.styleElement (scoping-shim.js:52)
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (element-mixin.html:636)
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (legacy-element-mixin.html:81)
```

I have the following index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>AppTest</title>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-layout.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-elements.html"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="bower_components/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js" async></script> -->
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <platinum-sw-register
      auto-register
      skip-waiting
      clients-claim
      reload-on-install
      href="sw-import.js">
      <platinum-sw-cache
        default-cache-strategy="networkFirst">
      </platinum-sw-cache>
    </platinum-sw-register>

    <app-header reveals>
      <app-toolbar>
        <div main-title>My app</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>
    <app-drawer id="drawer" swipe-open></app-drawer>
  </body>

  <script>
  </script>
</html>
```

and my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "polymer-2-carousel",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "platinum-sw": "PolymerElements/platinum-sw#2.0-preview",
    "app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#2.0-preview"
  }
}
```

As you can see the application is a skeleton very simple (just a test to start with) so there should not be much to get wrong or to investigate to find the cause of the error but I do not understand what is the problem and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem too, so I have to change these lines below in `bower-components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-register.html` file:

```
value: document._currentScript ? document._currentScript.baseURI :
      (HTMLImports.importForElement ? HTMLImports.importForElement(document.currentScript).baseURI :
      (document.currentScript ? document.currentScript.baseURI : './'))
```

To:

```
value: document._currentScript ? document._currentScript.baseURI :
      (document.currentScript ? document.currentScript.baseURI : './')
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  Does your fix eliminate both errors, or just the first one?  I'm trying to track down the cause of the second error (at `style-util.js:243`), which I'm seeing in an application that doesn't use `platinum-sw`.